# associating entities based on foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

I have an entity that is associated with several other entities based on their foreign keys.  I was hoping there was a way to associate the foreign entity without having to do its own query, like this:

```
original.Created = (from U in data.Users where U.UserID == createdID select U).FirstOrDefault();
```

I saw that you could do something like this ("data" is my DB connection):

```
original.Created = data.Users.Single(x => x.UserID == createdID);
```

Is that actually any better?  Or is there another way I'm not aware of to directly set the ID to make the association without costing another trip to the DB?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a LINQ query expression as you might noticed it looks like a query, the second one is just using the plain LINQ extension methods. They might look different, but the compiler treats them the same.

Its just a matter of preference, myself I prefer the extension methods as I find them more readable. This might not be the case in this case, but when the sequence gets longer it'll be harder to read.

Comment: I don't think they're equivalent because of the .FirstOrDefault v .Single but that is a relatively minor quibble

Comment: I definitely like the second one better from a "clean code" standpoint.  But is this the best I can do?  Is there no way to make this association without doing a query?  I ask because I have several of these associations that have to be made on the given entity, and I assume it's slowing things down a bit.

Comment: at Vald274 Indeed they are not. I just wanted to point out the compiler treats them the same and only the style of coding is different. @Starfleet Slowing down as in? Performance? There isn't really a faster way of doing this as far as I know. But again, there is no difference whether you use LINQ methods or LINQ queries.

Comment: Yes, performance.  I just thought there would be a better way of associating the entities rather than having to do multiple queries during my save.

Comment: I can't tell because I don't know your DB structure. But matching an user with an ID couldn't be much more shorter (thus faster) as the code you posted in the question.